# Create matrix from list of list of tuples using list comprehension

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, list-comprehension

I have a list of lists of tuples `list1`

```
list1 = [[('a',0.01),('b',0.23),('c',1e-7)],
      [('a',0.91),('b',0.067),('c',0.38)]]
```

and I want to create a numpy matrix where each row would be the second value of a tuple in `list1`. So the matrix, lets call it `A`, would have form

```
A = [[0.01,0.23,1e-7],[0.91,0.067,0.38]]
A.shape
>>> (2,3)
```

So far I have managed to achieve this in a slow and inefficient way

```
A = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    A.append(np.array([v for k,v in list1[i]]))
A = np.array(A)
```

**How can I do this using list comprehension?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need nested list comprehensions for this:

```
np.array([[tup[1] for tup in lst] for lst in list1])
Out: 
array([[  1.00000000e-02,   2.30000000e-01,   1.00000000e-07],
       [  9.10000000e-01,   6.70000000e-02,   3.80000000e-01]])
```

A better solution would be:

```
np.array(list1)[:,:,1].astype('float')
Out: 
array([[  1.00000000e-02,   2.30000000e-01,   1.00000000e-07],
       [  9.10000000e-01,   6.70000000e-02,   3.80000000e-01]])
```

Comment: Real nice. It's impressive the quantity of operations that can be written concisely in numpy.

Comment: Thanks @ayhan that really worked well.. weird thing is that your first solution is working faster than your second (better?) solution. I have a feeling that it has something to do with my data structure - my list of lists of tuples is actually an lda model using [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html), and the way you call on each list is `lda[corpus[i]]` which prints list `i`'s tuples.

Comment: @KillianTattan Yes, it is better in the sense that it is a direct numpy solution so it is more idiomatic for vectors. numpy doesn't handle object dtypes really well so the slowness is probably because of that. I suspect if you had a list of list of tuples whose values are numbers, numpy solution would outperform the list comprehension.